# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper> supportLib=28

Tags: android

This weird logcat messages started when I switched to supportLibrary 28, not happens on 27.1.1. I tried with an empty default project and the result exactly the same.

The problem is easily reproducible,

Create a new project with an empty activity and run on an emulator except API28 emulator. It'll give that error on my API21 emulator:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
```

My API24 device shows more detailed log:

```
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:11)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6666)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2844)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1572)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:110)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:203)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6364)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:924)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_9_
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.563 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:11)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6666)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2844)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1572)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:110)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:203)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6364)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
2018-11-15 22:00:55.564 9948-9948/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

I tried API21 emulator, API24 hardware device and API 28 emulator. Only API28 emulator didn't produce that error.

I googled, searched SO and also reported to [android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117685087) I can't find any solution and android team says that is an intended behavior. So I don't know what to do. Should I ignore an error message? Is there anybody have this issue?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does it actually cause any problems? It's an info-level log. You should probably report it on the issue tracker yourself.

Comment: No it doesn't. Application runs as expected. And yes I reported. It is info level but it produces an exception. Should I just ignore it?

Comment: any result ? I have same issue

Comment: @Web.11 Sorry, there is no result. I got used to living with this issue.

Comment: @SinanCeylan Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @RevanthKrishnaKumarV. Sorry, but no. And, It also happens on AndroidX

Comment: I have the exact same issue but found that it does cause app crash but only on certain devices.  In my case the crash is on NVidea tablet.  Most devices work but a few do crash and so far no resolution has been found.

Comment: For me it causes the app to crash on the Nexus 5X emulator that is running API 25.

Answer (score 7):

Well, as it appears that Google isn't interested in fixing it; I've decided to (for now) force using support library 27; at least it fixes the crashes on the few devices that support lib 28 crash on.

The fix that I'm using is adding the following into build.gradle however note, this is for a fix for android; only works for users of com.android.support libraries.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "27.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the above doing?  Why would I add this rather than just leaving the dependencies at a 27.x.x level?

Comment: If your project uses other 3rd party libraries, those libraries might import the newer support library (and newest wins).  The above code searches ALL dependencies in all libraries and replaces those with the specific version you want.  If you change only your dependencies you could end up with a newer version by way of some other dependency.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when using a class that is not compatible with your minimum sdk version. The code compiles because it leaves it up to you for deployment. Try using a higher min sdk version to verify this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not a solution for lower API devices. I mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace AppCompatActivity with Activity in `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`, the warning will be gone as the conflict is related to AppCompat in Android X.

However, not the best solution if you need to keep the backward compatibility for older devices. Otherwise you can just ignore this warning until any fix will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar issue and was getting the same error when trying to run any other application as well. Invalidating cache or setting "Launch Activity" to nothing did not work for me. But Running the application in a new emulator worked.